# How to avoid using Optional.get and Optional.isPresent

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring, option-type

```
public ValueA map(ValueB valueB, Date date) {
    Optional<ValueC> valueCOpt = find(valueB);
    if (valueCOpt.isPresent()) {
        ValueC valueC = valueCOpt.get();
        // call many getters on valueC and do a lot of logic with it.
        return map(/*some parameters*/);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This seems quite ugly. The advantage of optionals is completely gone in here. I read that one should rather use `map` or `flatMap` instead of `get`. But is it really a benefit if I replace every getter like

```
valueC.getFieldA()
```

with

```
valueCOpt.map(ValueC::getFieldA)
```

Do you know some common or best practices here?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ej0sss6cq14

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
public ValueA map(ValueB valueB, Date date) {
    return find(valueB)
        .map(valueC -> {
            // call many getters on valueC and do a lot of logic with it.
            return map(/*some parameters*/);
        })
        .orElse(null);
}
```

the key point is that the mapping function is only evaluated, if the optional is not empty, otherwise, the result stays an empty optional. `orElse(null)` will return `null` if the optional is empty.

Comment: and again... quite fast.

Comment: That's nice. A further refactoring would be to not return null but an empty optional. I could then write: find(valueB).map(valueC ->{
            // call many getters on valueC and do a lot of logic with it.
            return map(/*some parameters*/);}); That is: No `.orElse(null)` needed.

Comment: @Chris311 if `map(/*some parameters*/);})` return a Optional then you can use `find(valueB).flatMap( valueC -> map(...))` instead;

Comment: @holi-java: Is this what one should always try to achieve?

Comment: @Chris311 I'm not good at english, please say it more clearly. or ask Holger for helping.

Comment: Yes, you can just omit `.orElse(null)` to let the method return `Optional<ValueA>`, if changing the API is allowed, as it would require adapting all callers. If you have that option, it’s the right direction to go.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is to map, then a orElse(), or orElseThrow() if you need an exception

```
ValueA valueA = valueCOpt.map(valueC -> mapToValue(valueC))
       .orElse(null);
```

orElse() is used when you need a default value, in this case its `null`

Answer (score 1):

Given the line `return map(/*some parameters*/);`, are you intending to create a recursive call to your `map` method?

Assuming you are NOT attempting a recursive method call...

For clarification, I would remodel your method to look more this:

```
public Optional<ValueA> process(ValueB valueB, Date date) {
    Optional<ValueC> valueCOpt = find(valueB);
    if (valueCOpt.isPresent()) {
        ValueC valueC = valueCOpt.get();
        // call many getters on valueC and do a lot of logic with it.
        return Optional.of(new ValueA(/*results of above logic as parameters*/));
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Then I would refactor it to eliminate the `.isPresent` and `.get` method calls on `Optional` entirely, replacing them with `.map` which would look like this:

```
public Optional<ValueA> process(ValueB valueB, Date date) {
    return find(valueB)
        .map(valueC -> new ValueA(/*results of logic on valueC as parameters*/));
}
```

As you can see, the `.map` method is able to extract `valueC` from the `Optional<ValueC>` if `valueC` is present, and then the returned value is a wrapped `ValueA`. When the `.map` is called on the `Optional<ValueC>` and it is empty, then it automagically returns `Optional<ValueA>.empty()`.

In the event that during the processing of `valueC` it is discovered a `ValueA` cannot be instantiated, then `Optional.empty()` must be returned. This would require using `.flatMap` which would look like this:

```
public Optional<ValueA> process(ValueB valueB, Date date) {
    return find(valueB)
        .flatMap(valueC -> {
            // call many getters on valueC and do a lot of logic with it.
          boolean isValueCProcessingSuccessful = false;
          return (isValueCProcessingSuccessful)
              ? Optional.of(new ValueA(/*results of above logic as parameters*/))
              : Optional.empty();
        });
}
```